# (PHP MYSQLI) Strange 'No index used' error when I USE SELECT OR

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When i use mysqli prepared statement to make a query, I got this error:

```
No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT * FROM `signin_log` WHERE `account` = ? OR `account` = ? ORDER BY `log_id` DESC
```

The code is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `signin_log` WHERE `account` = ? OR `account` = ?  ORDER BY `log_id` DESC';
$params = array($username, $email);                                                                                                      
$result = (new AccountDAO())->executeQuery($sql, $params, 'ss');
```

Here is the table def:

```
create table `signin_log`(
  `log_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  primary key(`log_id`),
  `account` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  index(`account`),
  `accepted` char NOT NULL,
  `time` int NOT NULL,
  `ip` long NOT NULL
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

I know this error means the query does not contain an index in which the db has to scan the full table, but i think I do have used the index `account` and the pk`log_id`.

confusing.

I wonder if the 'OR' made this error happen--Mysql would not use index if you use OR, but i think it doesn't make sense.
Waiting for your help, thank you!

```
**Solved**
```

I found the answer from other pages([My simple MySql query doesn't use index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160694/my-simple-mysql-query-doesnt-use-index),[WHAT TO DO WHEN MYSQL DOESN’T USE AN INDEX…](http://jonathonhill.net/2009-05-01/what-to-do-when-mysql-doesnt-use-an-index/)(kind of old)).

There is nothing wrong with my query, neither with Mysql DBMS. This error is from php.

Here is what i got (it may from the manual, not sure, page is 404)

> Indexes are NOT used if MySQL can calculate that it will probably be
>   faster to scan the whole table. For example if key_part1 is evenly
>   distributed between 1 and 100, it’s not good to use an index in the
>   following query:
>
> SELECT * FROM table_name where key_part1 > 1 and key_part1 < 90

Indeed, I have few records in that table. When I tried to expand the num (about 30,000) everything clean.

So, to make PHP happy, i add this line:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

thanks to you all.

Comment: are you sure it's an error and not a warning?

Comment: Is there any difference if you use `IN` instead of `OR`? 

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM signin_log WHERE account IN (?, ?)  ORDER BY `log_id` DESC';`

Comment: It is a fatal error... And when i use IN instead, it remains.

Comment: @Rahul a fatal error

Comment: @mario.klump it remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small table or in a test environment mysql can use no index exen if it has been defined. Either way, you have to ask your database for the answer, by means of running an `EXPLAIN` query. Nobody else can tell you were your mysql used an index or not.

However, you can turn these warnings off. Instead of

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

make it

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

"key:null" IS a useful info, means no key has been used. For the reason I explained above. you shouldn't change your query but just get more data in your table.

`display_errors=E_ALL` have to remain the same in ALL environments.

Comment: it returned  "type:all, possible keys:account, key:null", seems no useful info.   By the way, in the test environment, i opened all the error reports in php.ini (display_errors=all). Must I use UNION instead of OR to make fix this?

Comment: thank you for your help, i solved this problem. the reason is that when scan the whole table is faster, dbms won't use index

Answer (score -1):

The missing index notification is a relatively low-severity warning.

The fatal error is in your PHP code, because of the following three conditions:

- mysqli reports a lot of warnings, even for relatively harmless conditions.
- You're throwing mysqli_sql_exception for all errors and warnings due to mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL) line.
- Your PHP code is not catching that exception (i.e. it's not in a try{} block with an appropriate catch(){} block), and uncaught exceptions are fatal. You can't do much about the first one, as mentioned in the other answer. So, you can fix it either by changing your mysqli_report(...) setting to MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT or MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF, or indeed anything other than MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL.

Another way to solve it is using:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

For best practices, and in combination with this, you should fix it properly by using try{} and catch(){} appropriately within your code.

Answer (score -1):

the "No index used in query/prepared statement" is not about PHP it's about your design table: simply ADD an index to your table.

really the best is turn ON the error/warnings in DEVELOP:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

but turn OFF warnings in production:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```